# SQL Compound Statement - Declare a variable

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to write a small SQL in mySQL but I get an error code whenever I try and run it.  I'm using the following guide to help with this coding, but I'm not sure if mySQL and this are compatible (pg 287): 
http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/rdb/pdf/gsp.pdf

```
BEGIN
DECLARE :mgrid CHAR(5) DEFAULT;
END;
```

The error code that mySQL gives me when I try and run this is: Error Code: 1064: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check that manual that corresponds to your MySQL syntax..."

Any thougts would be much appreciated!
Cheers

EDIT: Further - I can't even run the BEGIN - END; part, with no code in the middle...

Answer (score 1):

Dude, you're using an Oracle manual to code up some MySql sql?

That's like using your Ford manual to work on your Prius.

[Try the MySql manuals!](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/)

Here's the bit about [DECLARE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html)

Comment: haha, that could be it.  I'm new to the world of SQL...  I assumed that the SQL language was the same across platforms...

Comment: THey no doubt have lots in common, but enough differences to be a problem.  Like using a Ford manual for your Prius.

Comment: Cool - although I can definitely also see myself using a Form manual for a Prius...